# how to get partial page url using jquery & get selected index of accordion and store it in a global variable

Tags: jquery, jsp, accordion

I'm working on a web project, and I encountered this problem. I can't get it done after googling several days. So i'm asking for your help.

My main page(main.jsp) includes several different pages to make it up, the layout of my main page is shown as http://www.coderanch.com/t/613051/a/4352/main.png

And the partial page logic of menu.jsp is:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> mainMenu = new LinkedHashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
Map<String, String> oneSubMenu= new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
oneSubMenu.put("do something", "pages/xxx/xxx.jsp");
mainMenu.put("SubMenu One", oneSubMenu);
request.getSession().setAttribute("mainMenu", mainMenu);
```

In menu.jsp, use jquery-ui accordion and JSTL to build my MENU:

```
<div id="accordion" style="width:164px">
<c:forEach var="mainMenu" items="${sessionScope.mainMenu}">
<li><h3>${mainMenu.key}</h3>
<ul>
<c:forEach var="subMenu" items="${mainMenu.value}" varStatus="loop">
    <li><input type="button" class="linkbutton" value="${subMenu.key}" onclick="$('#content').load('${subMenu.value}')"/></li>
</c:forEach>
</ul>
</li>
```

When i click an item in MENU, it will load corresponding page into CONTENT(ID: content), e.g., above xxx.jsp will be loaded into CONTENT.

In navigation.jsp(partial of main.jsp), i want to show the current location, i.e., the loaded page url in CONTENT. my question here is: HOW TO GET THE PARTIAL PAGE URL LOADED INTO content?

OR IN THE OTHER HAND, how to get the selected item of accordion and save it to a variable that another JSP can use? for example, clicked item of "#accordion" is "do something" (url to load into CONTENT: "pages/xxx/xxx.jsp"), retrieve this and store it into a variable, which is declared in current page (menu.jsp) but must be accessed in another page (navigation.jsp).

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Here's a hint... using the `beforeActivate` method, why don't you console out both the `event` and `ui` objects. I bet you find your answer in there.

Comment: I tried beforeActivate and activate methods, when i click a header, both methods catch event, but how can i get the clicked item in the panel under each header? my code: alert(ui.newHeader.find("input").value); every item under each panel is a special class of "input:button".